# Laravel5 app in subfolder, authentication redirection not working

Tags: apache, authentication, laravel, laravel-5, subdirectory

I am facing strange problem. On my development environment (homestead) everything is working fine as I created virtual directory in nginx. But this app needs to be installed under subdirectory of apache root directory in production.

When I secure controller with middleware ("auth), it redirects to login page correctly. When I enter credentials, it redirects to "http://example.com/auth/login". I am not sure whats going wrong with it. I tried all options including changes in .htaccess as suggested in other posts but none is working.

Comment: Very same problem here!

Comment: please provide more detail by providing so code snippets. You might need to specify the full url in your template `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('auth/login') }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auth views have hardcoded URLs in them and they are causing these issues.

Go to "resources/views/auth/login.blade.php" and change

```
action="/auth/login"
```

with

```
action="{{ url('auth/login') }}"
```

---

Do the same for every action and href attributes throughout the "resources/views/auth" directory.

Comment: I made this change and the problem persisted. To fix the problem, I had to delete the storage files in storage\framework\views, which apparently kept the old login templates compiled. Once I changed that, the new template kicked in