# BASE URL Routing not working as intended

Tags: laravel, wampserver, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm reasonably new to Laravel, I've worked with Laravel 4 but decided to use the fancy new Laravel 5 for a personal project and to really learn it.

I thought of posting this over at Webmasters.SE but couldn't find any other questions regarding Laravel.

---

I couldn't find any solutions on the internet and I'll gladly provide more information.

---

So I just installed a fresh Laravel 5 application using their own [installaton how-to](http://laravel.com/docs/master) on my WAMP server locally. I did the whole Composer mumbo-jumbo, everything did it's job and no errors were shown.

---

**Problem**

Now here's my problem, when I access the site using `http://localhost/test.com/public/` I get the default page, just as it is supposed to be.

In the `routes.php` (shown below) you'll see that they defined a `home` route. So I typed it in my url bar as so `http://localhost/test.com/public/home` and I get redirected back to `http://localhost/test.com/public/auth/login`, as shown in the following image.
[image: auth] 
(It has no styling whatsoever, I'm asuming it is supposed to be like this?)

Anyway, I get there, and I hover over `Home` and the tiny url bar in the bottom left/right shows just `http://localhost` and clicking on it redirected me to the WAMP Server main page.

These are URLs they link to:

- Home -> `http://localhost`
- Login -> `http://localhost/auth/login`
- Register -> `http://localhost/auth/register`
- Forgot Password -> `http://localhost/password/email`

The required result is supposed to be that I should be redirected to `http://localhost/test.com/..`

I have no idea where this could've been caused, I'm *asuming* this is something that has to with `.htaccess`, `routes.php` or `paths` not being set correctly. I have tried modifying both `.htaccess` and `routes.php` but I clearly lack the knowledge to debug this problem by myself.

---

**Code resources** (fresh install, nothing has been changed)

routes.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure the `url` parameter in [`config/app.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/7cbe38c0a952029d1428d30810dbfe5c16d348e2/config/app.php#L29) (or your appropriate environment config file).  By default, this is set to `http://localhost`, so in your case you need to set it to `http://localhost/test.com/public/`.

**Edit**

It looks like the urls in the views are hard coded (for [example](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.0.0/resources/views/app.blade.php#L36)).  The fix is the same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28895478/3108853), which is to replace every hard coded url (eg `<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>`) with the `url()` helper (eg `<li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>`).

Comment: I've changed it, but it still shows the same behaviour. I've restarted WAMP Server a couple of times aswell.

Comment: It looks like the issue is actually with the default auth blades.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I had it working for a moment, but was messing with my WAMP and it decided to end it's life. But it did work! Thanks!

Comment: I made this change and the problem persisted. To fix the problem, I had to delete the storage files in storage\framework\views, which apparently kept the old login templates compiled. Once I changed that, the new template kicked in